# Why do pygame and pyglet show different results on the screen with the SAME matrices?

Tags: python, windows, opengl, pygame, pyglet

Why do I see different results when I run this code with `use_pyglet` being `True` vs. `False`?

The matrices and viewport are the same in both cases, so I'm really confused.

```
import ctypes
import numpy

use_pyglet = False   # change this to True to see the difference
if use_pyglet:
    import pyglet
    from pyglet.gl import *
    window = pyglet.window.Window(resizable=True, config=pyglet.gl.Config(double_buffer=True))
else:
    import pygame, pygame.locals
    from pyglet.gl import *
    pygame.init()
    pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480), pygame.locals.DOUBLEBUF | pygame.locals.OPENGL)
a = (ctypes.c_int   *  4)(); glGetIntegerv(GL_VIEWPORT, a); print numpy.asarray(a)
a = (ctypes.c_float * 16)(); glGetFloatv(GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX, a); print numpy.asarray(a).reshape((4, 4)).T
a = (ctypes.c_float * 16)(); glGetFloatv(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, a); print numpy.asarray(a).reshape((4, 4)).T
def on_draw():
    glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1)
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
    glColor4d(0, 0, 0, 1)
    glBegin(GL_LINE_STRIP)
    glVertex2d(0, 0)
    glVertex2d(100, 100)
    glEnd()
if use_pyglet:
    on_draw = window.event(on_draw)
    pyglet.app.run()
else:
    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                break
        on_draw()
        pygame.display.flip()
        pygame.time.wait(20)
```

PyGame:

[image: Screenshot]

Pyglet:

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The matrices and viewport are the same in both cases, so I'm really confused.

They actually aren't. The thing is that at the point where you check it they haven't been changed yet. If you instead move the check into `on_draw`. Then you'll notice that `GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX` for Pyglet will output:

```
[[ 0.003125    0.          0.         -1.        ]
 [ 0.          0.00416667  0.         -1.        ]
 [ 0.          0.         -1.         -0.        ]
 [ 0.          0.          0.          1.        ]]
```

While for Pygame it will output:

```
[[ 1.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  1.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  1.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  1.]]
```

The solution would be to setup the projection matrix yourself. Thus ensuring that it will always be the same.

```
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)
glLoadIdentity()
glOrtho(-1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0)

glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)
glLoadIdentity()
```

How you want to setup the project matrix of course depends on the desired result.

Comment: God, I wasted hours over this :( this was really dumb... thanks! +1

Comment: OpenGL can be a really confusing in the beginning. This wasn't directly an OpenGL problem, but always remember to check `glGetError()` and if possible then instead use [Debug Output](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Debug_Output).

Comment: Yeah, the thing is I've already done what I'm doing in C++, so I've gone through some of the rite of passage already. :\ It's just that I was doing it in Python now and it was blowing my mind how it could be wrong. Didn't realize I wasn't guaranteed an identity matrix initially...

Comment: To be honest that is quite weird of PyGame. There's also PyOpenGL which I've experienced to be a bit faster than pyglet, for more process intensive stuff.

Comment: You mean it's weird of Pyglet? (PyGame seems to be doing the right thing here right?) PyOpenGL doesn't have a windowing system though... not sure how you can use it on its own?

Comment: Yes, meant Pyglet! ;)